# formatting for concatenated string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to get this

```
$( "<div class=\"images\ style=\"background:url('" + item.link + "')no-repeat top center;\"/>").appendTo("#images").wrap("<a target=\"_blank\ href='" + item.link + "'></a>");
```

to output correctly but I'm not very hot on concatenating javascript strings. It's the line background div I can't get right.

cheers

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$( "<div class='images' style='background:url(" + item.link + ")no-repeat top center;'/>").appendTo("#images").wrap("<a target='_blank' href=" + item.link + "></a>");
```